# How a device will identify control and data packet?

Tags: networking, ethernet, packet

I think at **L2** it will be **ether type** and **destination MAC address**.
at **L3** it can be **protocol field** and **Destination IP Address**.

I want to know what are the other fields by which we can differentiate between control and data packet.

Comment: Unlike Wi-Fi, ethernet only has one frame type, and the frame header is really very simple. To ethernet, the payload is the data, and ethernet doesn't care what is in the payload, it simply passes the payload to the registered module with the EtherType in the frame header. Any differentiation between control or data is only relevant to an upper-layer protocol.

Comment: @Ron Maupin Now question how switch or router identifies control and data packet.

Comment: Switches are transparent devices that switch frames based on the destination MAC address, and nothing else. Routers don't care about the frames, they strip off and discard the data-link frame in order to get to the network packet, and they router the packet based on the destination network address. I think you have a misunderstanding about networking.

Comment: @Ron Maupin I have already written "ether type in the frame and destination MAC address .i.e ether type x8006 for ARP.

Comment: @Ron Maupin is my understanding is correct?

Comment: My point is that there is no distinction between control and data frames for ethernet. To ethernet, everything is a data frame, and it delivers the frame to a host based on the MAC address, and it sends the data (payload) to an upper-layer protocol inside a host, based on the EtherType. There is no concept of control or data frames in ethernet the way there is in something like Wi-Fi.

Comment: @Ron Maupin now please tell me "how a device will come to know which packet should be send control plane or date plane".
Till now you are unable to answer my query but jumping in the question. Please answer the question only if you know the correct answer.

Comment: Your question is about SDN then? You should mention that in the question...

Comment: It is generic not specific to SDN.

Comment: You simply son't understand that ethernet has no control or data frames. Wi-Fi does, but not ethernet. Ethernet frames are delivered from one host to another host by MAC address, and the payload of each frame is then sent to the process module in the host which is registered for that EtherType. Again, **there is no concept of control or data frames in ethernet.** Regular switches and routers will send something to the control plane which is destined to their own Network layer, e.g. IP, address, but that would be in the payload of a frame with their own destination MAC address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anupam Thakur: In pure L2 infrastructure, on receiving frame, node does the bridge-table/l2-table/cam lookup based on destination mac address. For different BPDUs (almost always reserved multicast mac dst addresses, few exceptions beyond the scope of this question) wherever required cam table is programmed with punt path to control-plane module (/also). Note, punt path doesn't distinguish between different protocols. It's job is to just push the packet in Q towards control-plane module. When cp module receives such packet, based on ethertype or LLC content it determines the further protocol processing of the packet.

Answer (score 0):

"Router Alert Option" in IP header can also force packet to be punted to Control Plane, even though it is not destined for recipient device. (i.e. transit node)

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal for answering my question.

Comment: can you tell how Switch (L2) will come to know it is control or date? I think at L2 it will be ether type and destination MAC address.

Comment: The IP header is in the layer-3 packet, not the layer-2 frame, so this doesn't really answer the question. Also, that option is disabled in most routers, especially Internet routers. @AnupamThakur, layer-2 switches are transparent devices, and frames do not hit the control plane of the switch. If the switch is a managed switch, it will have a layer-3 address, and only packets sent to the layer-3 management address will reach the control plane.

Comment: @Ron Maupin How a device will understand it is CDP(Cisco Discovery Protocol) ?  My question was for L2 and L3.